# backbone/mustache - How to apply a function on an ajax result

Tags: function, templates, backbone.js, render, mustache

I just need your help to apply a function on an ajax result before rendering it on my template. The official website [mustache on Github](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) gives us 2 examples by adding a method in the main object and uses it on template. But it does not work when using backbone fetch method.

```
postLists.query('{"date":"2014-06-03"}').fetch({
success:function(result){
// test result
    if(window.console) console.log(typeof(result)); // backbone object
    // add blue method
    result.blue = function () {return function (text, render) {return "<b style='color:blue;'>" + render(text) + "</b>";}};
    // check blue methode
    if(window.console) console.log(result); // blue method is added
    /* View */
    queryView = new Blog.Views.PostsListView({collection : postsList});
    /* rendering */
    queryView.render();
});

Template : 
<tbody>
{{#posts}}
<tr class="result"><td>{{id}}</td><td>{{ticket}}</td><td>{{gsm}}</td></tr>
{{/posts}}
</tbody>
```

It works perfectly but not if I am using blue method. is there a workaround to apply a method on backbone object before rendering ?
Thanks,

Comment: please read on the template {{#blue}}<td>{{ticket}}</td>{{/blue}}

Answer (score 0):

Your `result` variable has nothing to do with the rendering context of your view. You need to add `.blue` to either your collection or your model in order for it to be available when rendering your view. It's hard to say more than that, since you didn't show the source for PostsListsView :)